# Objective - C Inheritance

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

I have just started studying Objective - C..and I encountered a problem which I have been trying to solve for hours now..Here's my code..

ClassA.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// The ClassA Class

// @interface section
@interface ClassA: NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *x;
}
@property (copy,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *x;
- (void) initVar;
- (void) print;
- (void) addStr: (NSString *) str;
@end
```

ClassA.m

```
#import "ClassA.h"

// @implementation section
@implementation ClassA

@synthesize x;
- (void) initVar
{
    x = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void) print
{ 
    for(NSString *str in x)
        NSLog (@" --------- %@", str);

}

- (void) addStr: (NSString *) str
{
    if(![x containsObject: str])
        [x addObject: str];
}
@end
```

ClassB.h

```
#import "ClassA.h"

// The ClassB Class

// @interface section
@interface ClassB: ClassA
{
    NSMutableArray *y;
}
- (void) initVar;
- (void) print;
- (void) addStr: (NSString *) str;
@end
```

ClassB.m

```
#import "ClassB.h"

// @implementation section
@implementation ClassB

- (void) initVar
{
    y = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void) print
{ 
    for(NSString *str in y)
        NSLog (@" />>>>>>>>> %@", str);
}

- (void) addStr: (NSString *) str
{
    if(![self.x containsObject: str] && ![y containsObject: str])
    {
        [self.x addObject: str];
        [y addObject: str];
    }
    else if([self.x containsObject: str] && ![y containsObject: str])
    {
        [y addObject: str];
    }
}

@end
```

Here's where I'm calling the classes

```
#import "./MyClasses/ClassB.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
        NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSLog (@"This will print!");
    ClassB *b = [[ClassB alloc] init];
    ClassA *a = [[ClassA alloc] init];

    [a initVar];
    [a addStr: @"obj1"];
    [a addStr: @"obj2"];
    [a addStr: @"obj3"];
    [a print];

    [b initVar];
    [b addStr: @"YOH1"];
    [b addStr: @"YOH2"];
    [b addStr: @"YOH3"];
    [b print];

    NSLog (@" +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ");

    [a print];

    [a release];
    [b release];
        [pool drain];
        return 0;
}
```

---

I want it's output is like this..

This will print!
------------ obj1

------------ obj2

------------ obj3

/>>>>>>>>>>>> YOH1

/>>>>>>>>>>>> YOH2

/>>>>>>>>>>>> YOH3

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

------------ obj1

------------ obj2

------------ obj3

------------ YOH1

------------ YOH2

------------ YOH3

---

Currenty the last 3 output ( YOH1, YOH2 and YOH3) aren't showing. Meaning that I didn't add the object to `x`successfully. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the 'b' object doesn't even have an NSMutableArray in 'x'. 'x' will be nil for the object 'b'.

But I suspect there's a different misunderstanding here. The object 'b' and the object 'a' are two different objects. Just because class B is a subclass of A, doesn't mean that adding strings to some instance of class B is going to add those strings to some **other** instance of class A.

To answer your question in the comments, suppose you did want every instance of class B to have its own NSMutableArray in 'x'. You can do this like so:

```
// in ClassA.h
@interface ClassA: NSObject {
   NSMutableArray *x;
}

@property (retain,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *x;
@end

// in ClassA.m

@implementation ClassA
@synthesize x;

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {

      x = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      // whenever we init an instance of class A, we will have
      // an nsmutablearray in 'x'
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {

   // assume you aren't using ARC
   [x release];
   [super dealloc];
 }

// in ClassB.h
@interface ClassB: ClassA {
   NSMutableArray *y;
}

@property (retain,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *y; // for consistency
@end

// in ClassB.m

@implementation ClassB
@synthesize y;

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) { // call Class A's init

      y = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      // whenever we init an instance of class B, we will have
      // everything an instance of A has, plus this y we need
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {

    // assume you aren't using ARC
    [y release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I moved your initVar into a proper init, there's no reason to have two methods there. And I'm just showing the init's only, leaving out the addString and print.

So now you can do this:

`ClassB *instanceOfB = [[ClassB alloc] init];`

and that instance will have both the x and y arrays that you want.

I left the instance variable declarations in there also, even though they aren't strictly required with the newer compilers. The newer compiler versions can implicitly define those instance variables. If you don't understand that, don't worry about it at this point. Not that important.

I hope that helps.

Comment: That what I am trying to do. Hmm, what should I do to add strings to class A? Isn't initializing `x`for class B going to allocate another space in the memory, and not the one occupied by `x` of the class A?

Comment: So I think you are confusing classes with objects (instances of those classes). I would suggest some reading on that. Your object called 'b' is a different object from 'a'. So, yes, of course it needs its own memory for the array 'x'. So would an object 'a1' if you made another instance of class A. Or even 'a26'.

Comment: Each instance (object) of any class will needs its own memory for instance variables. You could create 100 instances of class A and you will have 100 nsmutablearrays called 'x'. One for each instance.

Comment: Ok reading Chapter 3 and 8. But before I have used NSMutableArray as my instance variable, I used `int x` as my variable. And I successfully print and assign values to it. Why is that?

Comment: Chapters 3 and 8 of what? If you have an instance variable (ivar) that is a primitive type like int, then you don't need to allocate an 'int' to put in there. That int (those 32-bits or whatever) are part of the structure of each object and will be initialized to zero for you. But still, setting that int on one object is not going to affect other objects. So that concept is still the same. Each object is still its own thing. Just like you and I are different instances of the same class called "human being". I can poke my eye out, and yours will be just fine.

Comment: Of the book, "Programming in Objective-C 2.0". So is there a way that I can get the instance variable `x` from ClassB?

Comment: Great, I've not read that book, but I'm sure he does a fine job of explaining the concept of classes and objects. The way it works in objective-c is conceptually very similar to Java, C#, Ruby, Python, etc. So the good news is if you understand it here, you understand the basic concept for all those as well. I will address your other question in an edit.

Comment: Thank you sir! I now know where I was wrong. But what if I want to add an object to `x` but not in `y` while still using the `addStr` method?

Answer (score 0):

But you have not added YOH1, YOH2 and YOH3 to `a`, have you?

Additionally, `x` will not be initialized for classB.